Prompt user to login with Spring Authorization Server
I am using Spring Security Authorization Server and I would like to always prompt the user to be redirected to the login page (even if already authenticated) as it is done with Google with the parameter prompt=select_account. It seems like the Spring Security Authorization Server is not supporting this prompt parameter out of the box.
Is there a way to tell the Auth server to check the authorization HTTP request for this prompt parameter and redirect the user to the login page ? Which Spring Security class(es) I should override ?
Thanks.

See this comment for an answer.
